# SQL INNER JOIN selects only one, last row from second table even if id matches

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

How to select all rows by id from second table? At the moment it selects only last row from second table if id matches.

**Query:**

```
SELECT

categories.category_id,
categories.category_name,
subcategories.subcategory_name,
categories.category_data,
categories.category_icon

FROM categories INNER JOIN subcategories ON

subcategories.category_id=categories.category_id";
```

**Full code:**

```
public static function getAllCategories()
{
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $sql = "
    SELECT c.category_id
         , c.category_name
         , s.subcategory_name
         , c.category_data
         , c.category_icon 
      FROM categories c
      JOIN subcategories s 
        ON s.category_id = c.category_id;
     ";

    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    $all_categories = array();

    foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $category) {

        array_walk_recursive($category, 'Filter::XSSFilter');

        $all_categories[$category->category_id] = new stdClass();
        $all_categories[$category->category_id]->category_id = $category->category_id;
        $all_categories[$category->category_id]->category_data = $category->category_data;
        $all_categories[$category->category_id]->category_icon = $category->category_icon;
        $all_categories[$category->category_id]->category_name = $category->category_name;
        $all_categories[$category->category_id]->subcategory_name = $category->subcategory_name;
    }

    return $all_categories;
}
```

**Photos:**

This is what I should get:

[image]

And this is what I have:

[image]

First table properly selects all rows, but second table selects only last row if id matches. How to select all rows from second table?

Comment: use LEFT JOIN for all ROW in the left table

Comment: this does not work. LEFT JOIN selects all rows from categories table, but keep same for subcategories table. It selects only one last row for second table.

Comment: This should select all matching categories and subcategories. Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data, and explain what you're expecting different from what it produces?

Comment: can you post a sample and the result that you want

Comment: Just a minute. I will edit my question with full codes

Comment: use RIGHT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Comment: @AshishChoudhary He says the IDs match, so he doesn't need to use `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join. That's only to get rows that have no match.

Comment: @Barmar He says  "select all rows by id from second table" which is the case of RIGHT JOIN. so that not existing Ids also come up in the records.

Comment: Please see edited question

Comment: @Tauras Where is the contents of the original tables? Can you post plain text instead of an image so we can copy and paste it? Or make a sqlfiddle like I asked earlier.

Comment: @Tauras Cars, Buses etc are coming from sub_categories table?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query:**

```
SELECT

categories.category_id,
categories.category_name,
subcategories.subcategory_id,
subcategories.subcategory_name,
categories.category_data,
categories.category_icon

FROM categories INNER JOIN subcategories ON

subcategories.category_id=categories.category_id";
```

**EDIT**

```
$subCat = array();
foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $category) {

     array_walk_recursive($category, 'Filter::XSSFilter');

     $subCat[$category->category_id][] = $category->subcategory_name;

     $all_categories[$category->category_id] = new stdClass();
     $all_categories[$category->category_id] = $category;
     $all_categories[$category->category_id]->subcategory_name = (object) $subCat[$category->category_id];
}
```

**While getting the data:**

```
<?php foreach ($this->categories as $category) { ?>
    <?= $category->category_data; ?>
    <?php foreach ($category->subcategory_name as $subcategory) { ?>
        <?= $subcategory; ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me, why using your code, no need to use something like this: ``$all_categories[$category->category_id]->category_name = $category->category_name;`` to display data? Since i am displaying it like this: ``<?php foreach ($this->categories as $category) { ?> <?= $category->category_data; ?><?php } ?>``

Comment: @Tauras `(array)` converts the object to an associative array. It's the same as if you had use `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: Replace `$all_categories[$category->category_id] = new stdClass();` with `$all_categories[$category->subcategory_id] = new stdClass();`
Do this for all `$all_categories[$category->category_id]`
You need to replace `category_id` with `subcategory_id`.
Also, you need to include `subcategories.subcategory_id` in your field selection.

Comment: I used array just to simplify things. You can continue using objects as well. Also please implement above mentioned fixed in the last comment.

Comment: I did everything both of you said, but now i have other error. ``Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) ``. I am banging my head for 2-3 hours for this select query.

Comment: Almost. With your code, now it displays in reverse. 1 subcategory, but as much categories with same name as subcategories has matching id :D

Comment: Its like targeting the dart in the dark. :) Can you please post both the tables rows which needs to be worked upon. Just the image of both tables with rows would be fine.

Comment: Same.. everything in reverse.

Comment: As I can see `$category->category_data;` is used to show "Transport".
How do you manage to show "Others"?

Comment: category_data is used in data-attribute in html. Your edited code kinda works only with subcategory_name, but category_name gives me error ``Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in``

Comment: Can you post the file where you are showing the category? I need to see where and how the HTML is created.

Comment: For testing purpose, i just copy/paste your code as it is. Subcategories are OK, but now, the problem is with categories. It gives error. ``Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in``. It gives tons of errors because of ``$all_categories[$category->category_id]->category_id = $category->category_id;`` and other similar lines, which should get data from $categories. As i said $subcategories is OK.

Comment: I need to see your view code where you display the categories and subcategories. I am not sure how you are currently iterating through them.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary here your go: ``http://84.240.14.122/function.png`` and ``http://84.240.14.122/view.png``

Comment: Thanks! Your Screenshots helped a lot. I think its solved now. Try the code in "EDIT" and "While getting the data:". It should do the needful. :)

Comment: Thanks, that working just fine. Just one question. Is this as safe as the original function?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary and one more question.. if i am adding html to your view code, than the problem is the same. Code displays only last row. If code is using without html, than everything is OK. However, you answered my original question, but if you know how to fix this new problem, please help :)

Comment: @AshishChoudhary nope, that was my mistake. Forget about new problem, just answer if you cant about security. Is this as safe as original function?

Comment: There is nothing to be worried about security here. Everything is coming from the DB. Only select queries. And there's nothing much I changed here. Suppose you want to have one more field from DB in future so you just have to add that field in the query. You dont have to change anything in the function in that case and you can get the new field in the view/html.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your PHP. Each time through the loop you **replace** `$allCategories[$category->category_id]` with the data from the current row. So when the loop is done, it only contains the data from the last row.

You should make a multidimensional array. When a row contains the same category as a previous row, push the new object onto the array.

```
foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $category) {

    array_walk_recursive($category, 'Filter::XSSFilter');

    if (!isset($allCategories[$category->category_id])) {
        $allCategories[$category->category_id] = array();
    }
    $all_categories[$category->category_id][] = $category;
}
```

There's no need to make a new `stdClass` object and copy each property, since `fetchAll` returns a new object for each row. You can just put that object into the array.

Comment: It gives me errors. One of them: ``Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in``

Comment: Did you set your fetch mode to `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`?

Comment: I'm using the same object syntax as your original code. I don't see how mine would get that error when yours didn't.

Comment: ``$options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);``

Comment: Use $all_categories[$category->category_id][] = (array) $category; 
Also, there is no need of if statement here.

Comment: I have no clue how to make this to work. I think code is good, but still i get errors or not full displayed rows.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I don't like depending on the automatic creation of sub-arrays when you use `[]` syntax, I prefer to make it explicit.

Comment: @Barmar Yes you are right. We define array explicitly when we need to make sure that its not already defined and if it is defined then it should not add on the new values to existing array. But in this case we dont need it as we are creating new array into the loop only. Suppose the array we are crating are already existing outside the loop then also the if condition check will fail as it checks if its set.

Comment: That's OK. We still push onto the array if it's already set before the loop.

Comment: My assignment to `[]` is outside the `if`.